# Android: Keeping the soft keyboard open even on clicking the done button

Tags: android

[image]

Here, by clicking the `done` button, the soft keyboard automatically shuts down, but I want to keep it open.

Here's the current code inside the `onCreate()` method.

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

etPIN.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            String pin1 = etPIN.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(PINActivity.this, pin1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            tvPINGuide.setText(getString(R.string.confirm_pin));
            etPIN.setText("");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return `true` from your overrided method `onEditorAction`, s*ystem does not going to handle the action again*. So, In this case you should return true to not hide keyboard when action is `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`.

Here use this code:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

          }
          return true;
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

if your return true from your onEditorAction method, action is not going to be handled again. In this case you can return true to not hide keyboard when action is EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE.

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // do your stuff here
if (editText.getText().toString().equals(PIN)) // they entered correct
       {
           // log them in
           return false; // close the keyboard
       }
       else
       {
           Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true; // keep the keyboard up
       }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert this snippet inside the overrided onKey method when the done key is detected

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Source https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this , its simple

```
etPIN.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                  //do your stuff here
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

It will help you definitely

```
etPIN.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
{
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent)
        {
            if((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                String pin1 = etPIN.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(PINActivity.this, pin1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                tvPINGuide.setText(getString(R.string.confirm_pin));
                etPIN.setText("");
            }
            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION) // when done button pressed
            {
                // it will open your keyboard again here
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(etPIN.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                etPIN.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```