# Issue with android softkeyboard when typing onto texarea inside webview

Tags: android, webview, soft-keyboard

i have designed a chat app with android webview which has a textarea and  a button.The purpose of button is to send the input text like u see in whatsapp.The problem with my app is that when i click on the send button or outside the textarea, anywhere on webview the soft-keyboard automatically hides quickly and it reappears only if i click inside the textarea again.I have tried many solutions still no luck.my goal is to prevent the soft-keyboard from hiding on whatever events occuring on webview.pls suggest a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136625/android-keeping-the-soft-keyboard-open-even-on-clicking-the-done-button

Comment: My issue was with the textarea of webview.i managed to solve this problem by calling focus method on textarea when button is clicked.The issue has been solved

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself.I am posting it here so that it may help anyone in the future.This is the html code that caused problem in android webview

```
 <div class="chat-input">

      <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="message">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="send">Basic</button>

    </div>
```

The problem i encountered was when the send button is pressed,the soft-keyboard dismisses itself.i think this is because of textarea loses its focus.The solution is to call focus method on textarea.like this

```
$("#send).click(function(){
    $("#message").focus() ;
    sendmessage();
})
```